# How to inject library into Android zygote process?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I want to write a application to inject library into the android process. Above all I have to

map a secure memory in the remote process,it used to perform the function of the injection.

Now the problem here and all of the processes are able to achieve memorymapping except Zygote!

Although I setting the LR register equal 0x00000000, but still blocking in waitpid()

----- I did not receive SIGSEVG signal,I hope you give me help, thanks.

[**GETTING SOURCE**](https://bitbucket.org/mikukon/android-test/overview)

```
   //fake saved return address, triggering a SIGSEGV to catch
    regs->ARM_lr = 0x00000000;

    ptrace_setregs( pid, regs );

    ptrace_cont(pid);

    int status;
    int id = 0;
    do {
            id = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);//The process was blocked ....! Why..?
            printf("[+] id:%d,signal:%d\n",id,WSTOPSIG(status));
    } while ((id != pid) || (WSTOPSIG(status) != SIGSEGV));
```

Comment: If you have root to be able to ptrace zygote, you should also be able to shut it down ("stop" for example from the adb command line) and start up a patched replacement - the result will look on the GUI very much like a device reboot, though in actuality only the android runtime has been restarted.